# Разметка, стили, скрипт из Local Storage

Tags: javascript, html5

Задался целью минимизировать трафик, увеличить скорость последующих загрузок, при повторном посещении сайта. Желательно исключительно нативным JS, а также при помощи различных фреймворков, JQuery, Bootstrap и т.д.

**Цель:** При первом посещении сайта, записать разметку в локал Local Storage, также по возможности стили, скрипты. (желательно записывать после загрузки страницы пользователем, чтоб не причинять неудобств пользователю при первом посещении).

При повторном посещении сайта - выгружать из Local Storage все что записали. Также не лишним была бы проверка на наличие изменений перед выгрузкой но это уже бонус а не основная задача.

Понятно что все кодировать будем скорее всего при помощи: `encodeURIComponent`, декодировать обратно при `decodeURIComponent`. (может вы знаете лучший способ?)
Так ка я недавно изучаю JS прошу помощи в реализации механизма записи/чтения из Local Storage всей разметки, если такое возможно. Полезно знать будет в любом случае.

Comment: А чем Вас не устраивает имеющийся в любом браузере механизм кэширования, предназначенный ровно для того, чтобы `минимизировать трафик, увеличить скорость последующих загрузок при повторном посещении сайта`?

Comment: Дополнение к Yaant - только надо чуть чуть доработать кеширование на стороне сервера, поместить все скрипты в папку в которой отдаются заголовки о статичном контенте (в апач например это делает mod_expires), тогда браузер сам отлично все хранит и даже не пытается перезапрашивать. При изменении скриптов надо что бы к их url добавлялась версия или например как решает задачу яндекс - именем скрипта является его md5 и система контроля версий подставляет правильные имена при отдаче страницы

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к комментариям. Задача Local Storage - не кэширование файлов, а хранение каких-то одиночных данных, которые вам могут потребоваться в работе, некий аналог мини-базы данныъ, только в браузере. 
Даже не думайте, чтобы хранить в Local Storage разметку страниц, скрипты, стили, для этого есть механизм кэширования на сервере и клиенте. С кэшированием на стороне клиента все более менее - практически все браузеры прекрасно справляются с кэшированием. Кэширование на стороне сервера предполагает настройку заголовков ответа, и опять же вне зависимости от технологии сервера -PHP, ASP.NET и т.д. везде кэширование прекрасно работает. Ваша задача - только настроить заголовки ответа.